# how do I find the kerner version in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to find the kernel verion running on my system. I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 with  the gnome desktop because  a failed ati/amd driver install moofed my unity desktop and I haven't been able to get it back...even though I've removed the offending  drivers and re-installed the generic version that came with the original install.

Answer (score 1):

To know kernel version you have to execute this command:

```
 uname -r
```

It would display something like:

```
 3.8.0-30-generic
```

You can also get the complete list by:

```
 uname -a
```

It would display something like:

```
 Linux saurav-P4I45Gx-PE 3.8.0-30-generic #44~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 17:33:45 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Another way to know the kernel version is to open `Synaptic Package Manager` and search for `linux header`. You have to check for the installed `Kernel` version.

Yet another way to find the kernel version is to run this command:

```
 sudo dpkg -l | grep linux-headers | grep ii
```

or

```
 sudo dpkg -l | grep linux-headers | awk '{print $3}'
```

That's it..